# How can I add a close button in this popup

Tags: jquery, popup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function media_player(url){
    embed = '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://flash-mp3-player.net/medias/player_mp3_maxi.swf" width="200" height="20">'+
            ' <param name="movie"  value="http://flash-mp3-player.net/medias/player_mp3_maxi.swf" />'+
            ' <param name="FlashVars" value="mp3='+url+'&amp;showstop=1&amp;showvolume=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;slidercolor2=CECDCC&amp;sliderovercolor=CECDCC&amp;buttonovercolor=CECDCC&amp;loadingcolor=CECDCC" />'+
            '</object>';

    jQuery('#media-popup .content').html(embed);
    jQuery('#media-popup').fadeIn();
  }
</script>
```

How can i add a close button?

Comment: Here is code: http://pastebin.com/F1aJC8c2

Comment: $("#media-popup").fadeOut(); OR $("#media-popup").hide();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the jquery function `.fadeOut()` ?

```
$("#media-popup").fadeOut();
```

Comment: if i use this code its show popup and then fadeout is it possible to make fadeout when user click?

Comment: Yes, `$("#yourbuttonid").click(function() { $("#media-popup").fadeOut(); });`

Comment: Thanks for the help. now problem... audio still running after fadeout

Comment: You can't stop that. Maybe you can delete the element?

Answer (score 0):

Assign an ID to the object you want to close (I guess in your case is the object tag). Then create an element which is responsible to close it when clicked. For example:

```
$('<div>')
    .attr('id','close-panel-button')
    .appendTo($('body'))
    .click(function(){

        $('#id-of-the-object-to-close-here').hide();

    });
```

You can change the hide method with whatever method your prefer, depending how you want to close it. Style your close-panel-button accordingly (eg position: absolute; and custom coordinates).